# jQuery Mouseenter and mouseleave actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, onmouseover, onmouseout, onmouseup

I am using the following jQuery script:

```
$("#divid").mouseenter(function() {
    $('#divid').show(1000);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('#divid').hide(1000);
});
$("#hldiv").mouseenter(function() {
    $('#divid').show(1000);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('#divid').hide(1000);   
});
```

As you can see, when the mouse hovers over a hyperlink called `#hldiv`, the `#divid` should be shown. The main goal is to keep the `DIV` shown if the mouse is over the `DIV` - but the `#divid` should not be visible initially.

If the mouse moves over the hyperlink, the `DIV` should appear, and when the mouse then moves over the `DIV`, it should stay until the mouse leaves.

The problem is that with my current code, when the user moves over the hyperlink and then out - the `DIV` appears/disappears correctly, but when the user moves out of the hyperlink and over the `DIV` itself, the `DIV` also disappears.

How should I fix this?

Comment: Are the elements DLDIV and DIVID next to each other on the page ?

Comment: Whut... care to slap an example on jsFiddle.net, including your HTML (that bit is important too).

Comment: @Russ C , the hlDiv is inside another div and above that div the divid comes. like 
<div>
...
<hlDiv></hlDiv>
...
</div><div ID="divId"></div>

Comment: @aeciftci plaes post an examplke on jsfiddle.net as Ben suggested

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w68YX/2/ this is jsfiddle link, it is not working now so think as a template the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add a container and do:

```
<div id='container'>
<a ID="hlDiv">hlink</a>
<div ID="divId">Test Test Test</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hlDiv").hover(function() {
        $('#divId').show(1000);
    })
        $('#container').mouseleave(function(){
            $('#divId').hide(1000);
        });
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/w68YX/8/

Comment: Ok @Nicola, thank you this worked. But i want a more efficient way because there are some extra hyperlinks with the hlDiv and they are in same container too, so I need to seperate the hlDiv from them but how?

Comment: I edited the fiddle: look here http://jsfiddle.net/w68YX/13/ but i really do think you should use a container

Comment: last fiddle is not working properly :), but i guess i will go after the container idea too, thank you so much for saving me from some trouble, have a good life.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, rewriting

```
$("#divid").mouseenter(function() {
    $('#divid').stop(true);
    $('#divid').show(1000);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('#divid').hide(1000);
});
```

Might help, since it stops the current animation (fading out) and fades it back in (if it has already turned a bit transparent).

However this depends on your HTML, and might not work in your case, so please post the structure also.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/w68YX/2 this is the structure, not so complex.

Answer (score 0):

I am very late to this party - but there is a far better way to do this, so I want to add it for the sake of future browsers. You don't need jQuery for this effect *at all.*

First, wrap the two items in a container (here I'm using a div with class `container`), and  apply a class to the item you want to appear/disappear on hove (here I'm using the `show-on-hover` class on the `#divId` element)

```
<div class="container">
  <a id="hlDiv" href="...">link text</a>
  <div class="show-on-hover" id="divId">popup stuff</div>
</div>
```

Next, set up your CSS as follows:

```
.container > .show-on-hover { display: none; }
.container:hover > .show-on-hover { display: block; }

#divId { /* whatever styles you want */ }
```

The effect is that the hover is now controlled entirely by CSS - but, it doesn't have the 1s transition you originally had. This is a little more complicated (and currently doesn't work in IE - but will be supported as of IE10).

Simply change the CSS as follows:

```
.container { position: relative; }
.container > .show-on-hover { opacity: 0.0; position: absolute; }
.container:hover > .show-on-hover { opacity: 1.0; }

.show-on-hover {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s; /* Chrome / Safari */
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;    /* Firefox */
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;      /* Opera */
}
```

The relative positioning on the `.container` means that the container sets its own bounding boxes for its child elements and their positioning. This means that when you then set the `> .show-on-hover` styling to `position: absolute;`, it will still be constrained to its parent (if you set `left: 0;` as an example, it will move to the left edge of the `.container`, rather than the screen).

The `opacity` toggle now simply makes the absolutely positioned item show/disappear wherever you've placed it (and you would update the CSS to put it exactly where you want, relative to the hyperlink). Because we're no longer using `display: none` - the `DIV` will always take up space on the screen - even when hidden (which is probably not what you want).

Finally - the last block, which sets transitions, tells modern browsers that whenever the opacity changes on elements of class `.show-on-hover`, make that change happen as a tween over 1s of duration.

Here is a jsFiddle showing the transitions: http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/nHrXK/2

And here is a jsFiddle showing just the toggle: http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/nHrXK/3/